# Netbeans: how to include other c++ static library project?

Tags: c++, netbeans

I am really new to c++ and am using Netbeans for now.

I managed to create a Sign.h and Sign.cpp containing a working class `Sign`.
I added these to a Console Project and it works great:

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <ostream>
  #include "Sign.h"

  int main()
  {
      Sign sign = Sign::parse("b");
      std::cout << sign.toString() << " " << sign.getValue() <<"\n";
  }
```

However, I want to create a static library containing the `Sign` class, so I created a static library and added `Sign.cpp` and `Sign.h` to it. The problem now is, that I can't seem to get my Sign class to be included in the main console program.

I added the library in `Options => Build => Linker => Libraries`, and added it to the `required projects`. However I can't use `#include <Sign>` or `#include <Sign.h>`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need two files from a library. The library file (.lib on windows, .a on linux) and the include file (.h files).

The Options => Build => Linker => Libraries is only for the library file. You also need to set the path for the includes under File => Project Properties =>
  Build => C++ Compiler => General => Include Directories