# Trouble when running autogen.sh

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I have downloaded R tree from http://libspatialindex.github.com/

Since on running ./autogen.sh I was getting file/folder not found, therefore I downloaded the file autogen.sh from the github repository given below:

https://raw.github.com/libspatialindex/libspatialindex/9a5a2f4d83c3ec7be4dbf2c8a86341703d837185/autogen.sh

Now when I run **./autogen.sh** I am getting "Permission denied"
And if I run **sh ./autogen.sh** I am getting:

```
glibtoolize or libtoolize not found. Giving up!
```

Please suggest what should I do now

**EDIT:Also I want to use libspatialindex inside my C++ project. I am using netbeans. I mean I want to use the functions inside libspatialindex inside my netbeans project. How should I use the same. Right now I have run the config and make command in a separate directory. I am not getting as to how to use them inside my project.**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Install `libtool` from your package manager.

Comment: Also I want to use libspatialindex inside my C++ project. I am using netbeans. I mean I want to use the functions inside libspatialindex inside my netbeans project. How should I use the same. Right now I have run the config and make command in a seperate directory. I am not getting as to how to use them inside my project.

Comment: Also thanks a lot for the prompt response. A gentle request..pls suggest a solution to my above mentioned problem also.

Comment: See some similar C++-library-in-Netbeans questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7799493/include-c-library-in-netbeans-7-0) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264294/netbeans-how-to-include-other-c-static-library-project)

Answer (score 4):

To fix the 'Permission Denied' error you need to edit the permissions of your autogen.sh file. Run this command:
`chmod +x autogen.sh`

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after restoring a library from a Backup to a NTFS directory.
I discovered that another reason this can occur is if the mounted partition has `noexec` flag on it.

1. Run `mount` to see if `noexec` has been set on the partition.
2. Update `/etc/fstab` or add `-o exec` to the mount command.

Hope, it helps others in the same situation as me.