# adding custom library to netbeans for C++

Tags: c++, netbeans

I've recently started watching STanford's cs106B lectures on youtube, and I've downloaded their "Stanford C++ Libraries" that they've made. I've right-clicked my project, and added the whole folder (named "cs106lib-0.3.1") to the "Include directories" and "Include Headers" sections" but when I import one of the headers "vector.h" and create an object using it it says "unable to resolve identifier vector", and the compiler says the folder doesn't exist, although it's definitely on my desktop. Sorry, if this question has been asked then I can't find it, but I have been stuck looking for the past day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mix include directories and -headers.

- **Include directories:** Adds directories where your header files are
- **Include headers:** Adds single header files

Also make sure your paths are ok. Let's assume a structure like this:

```
cs106lib-0.3.1
|
+-- include
|   |
|   +-- Example1.h
|   |
|   +-- subdir/Example2.h
|
+-- ...
```

In this case you have add the directory `cs106lib-0.3.1/include` to include *directories*.

Now you can use it like this:

```
#include "Example1.h"
#include "subdir/Example2.h"
// ...
```

Also don't forget to add the **binaries** (if you have) to linker flags.

**TIP:** Use the code completion to see where you are; eg. type `#include "../" <Ctrl+Space>` to see files and directories available for to include.

Comment: Oh okay, so I can't just add the entire folder to "include directories" to encompass all the header files?   Also, I'm not sure what you mean by your last comment to add binaries to linker flags..Sorry about that, I'm still very VERY new.

Comment: You *can* add the entire folder, but it's not good practice and not recommended. If you do so, you have to change the path in your include directive (eg. `#include "include/Example1.h"`). But again, this is very, very  unusual. Btw, if you are new to this, you can find useful information on the [NB C/C++ learning trail](https://netbeans.org/kb/trails/cnd.html).

Comment: If your library has binaries (= the compiled library), you have to tell the linker what files he has to link to your program (and where to find). Some info about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264294/netbeans-how-to-include-other-c-static-library-project

Comment: Ok that makes sense now. Thank you very much, and thanks for the provided links I'll be checking those out!